# VBA comparação de items e adicinamento de quantia

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, visual-basic-6

Pessoal hj vim trazeinserir a descrição da imagem aquir uma duvida que sera bem especifica não sei qual problema desse codigo na vdd xP fiquei uns dias quebrando a cabeça nele mas ainda não achei uma solução usei um loop para ele repetir uma condição de forma que ele nao para ate chegar a ultima celula preenchida.

```
 Sub finalizaVenda()

v_id = Sheets("venda").Cells(3, 8)
g_id = Sheets("ger").Cells(3, 1)

i = 3

val_venda = Sheets("venda").Range("k3").Value
val_ger = Sheets("ger").Cells(i, 1).Value

indConsulta = Sheets("venda").Range("H1048576").End(xlUp).row
Sheets("venda").Activate
Sheets("venda").Range("h3").Select

Do While ActiveCell.row >= 3

If (v_id = g_id) Then

val_ger = val_venda
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
i = i + 1
Debug.Print val_ger
Debug.Print val_venda
Sheets("ger").Cells(i, 3).Select

Else

i = i + 1

End If
Loop
End Sub
```

oque era para acontecer era o seguinte : todos id's que forem apresentados num periodo de **h3 a h21 da tabela venda**,
teriam que ser comparados a coluna **A da tabela ger** que possui todos id's cadastrados. Caso o id do periodo **h3 a h21 da tabela venda** coincidir com algum id da **coluna A da tabela ger**
ent a quantia que for imposta na coluna **QUANTIDADE da tabela venda** deve ser "jogada" na celula **Q.venda de acordo com seu id** de forma que o valor da **k3(venda)** possa ser limpa e a celula que for preenchida com esse valor na **tabela ger** consiga receber outros valores + o msm
bom um exemplo seria a seguinte situação:

informo o id e a quantidade da venda(tabela venda) id = 1 & quantidade = 5
quando eu for finalizar a venda clico no botao, e ele joga esse quantia na tabela ger, nesse caso a celula e3 seria preenchida com 5 por o id ser 1.
caso eu venha fazer outra venda com msm id ele adiciona a quantia que informei em cima da quantia 5 somando os dois valores.

[image: tabela venda]
[image: tabela ger]

Comment: Você está realizando um while loop da linha 3 até a última linha da planilha com `Do While ActiveCell.row >= 3`, tente usar `Do While ActiveCell.row >= indConsulta` e tente evitar o uso do `.Select`

Comment: opa, boa noite amg, fiz oq me disse porem da o msm erro. Entra em um loop e simplesmente trava o programa, sobre o while loop eu tava usando o while como uma condição para executar um outra condição , tipo.. (enquanto o indice row da celula ativa for menor que a ultima linha preenchida ) se(o id na coluna coincidir com o id na tabela) então (a quantida de produto vai ser ela msm + a quantia informada na coluna Quantia ). o select ele foi usado para selecionar uma celula e ele ser usado como um cursor que percorre a coluna id, bom pelo menos isso era minha ideia xD